# GKE Node Anti-Affinity but on node level not kube resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have GKE cluster, 2 node pools and around 9 helm charts, only 1 helm chart should use one node pool and all other charts use the other one, I made on this 1 chart the node affinity to go only to the specific node pool - but is there a way to create node anti-affinity on node pools? or do I have to create anti-affinity on all the other 8 charts so they use only second node pool? Seems kinda excessive and there should be easier way but I don't see it in docs.

Answer (score 2):

The principle is to deploy pod on node. When this operation is performed, the constraints are checked (CPU, Memory, affinity, nodeSelector,...) and enforced

So, if you want to prevent execution on the specific node pool for the 8 other charts, yes, you need to explicitly set on each pod their affinity or antiAffinity.

You can also use the NodeSelector feature for this.